# How to enter a formula into a cell using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to enter a formula into a cell which contains variable called var1a?
The code that I have is:

```
    Worksheets("EmployeeCosts").Range("B" & var1a).Formula = ""SUM(H5:H""& var1a)
```

But it enters into an excel worksheet with a mistake.

Comment: What does "it enters into an excel worksheet with a mistake" mean?

Answer (score 20):

You aren't building your formula right.

```
Worksheets("EmployeeCosts").Range("B" & var1a).Formula =  "=SUM(H5:H" & var1a & ")"
```

This does the same as the following lines do:

```
Dim myFormula As String
myFormula = "=SUM(H5:H"
myFormula = myFormula & var1a
myformula = myformula & ")"
```

which is what you are trying to do.

Also, you want to have the `=` at the beginning of the formala.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it like this:

```
Worksheets("EmployeeCosts").Range("B" & var1a).Formula = _
Replace("=SUM(H5:H{SOME_VAR})","{SOME_VAR}",var1a)
```

In case you have some more complex formula it will be handy