# Cell formula using a variable

Tags: excel, excel-r1c1-notation, vba

I'm using the Excel VBA Editor (I have both Excel 2007 and Excel 2016). I have a variable parameter `i`, all the others are fixed.
Could you please say me how I can put a formula in a cell `Cells(i, 2)`?

1. using variables from my macro (`j1`, `j2`, `i1`)
2. using variables from my worksheet (the cells J1, J2, `C[-1]`)

`C[-1]` being the cell left of `Cells(i, 2)` eg. `Cells(i, 1)`?

Thans a lot,
Eduard

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807505/how-to-enter-a-formula-into-a-cell-using-vba    and     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744537/vba-setting-the-formula-for-a-cell

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807505/how-to-enter-a-formula-into-a-cell-using-vbaCells(i, 2).Formula = "=Date("&j1&";"&j2&";C[-1])"

Comment: based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807505/how-to-enter-a-formula-into-a-cell-using-vba, I would write Cells(i, 2).Formula = "=Date("&j1&";"&j2&";C[-1])" but **it doesn't work**

Comment: You need to make it on Excel VBA, so you should create somethink like: Worksheets("Sheet_NAME").Range(Cells(i,2)).Formula =  "=DATE(J1;J2;C"& i & ")" 
---- and use a For i=1 to Last_Row

ps.: Syntax: DATE(year,month,day) and the formula will be insert on the line 'i' and column B  and the DATE fomula will get data from J1;J2; column C line 'i'

Comment: it's exactly what I did. The compilator just says "compilation error: syntax error" and points to ","

Comment: I added an answer

Comment: I just forgot the spaces: "&i&" instead "& i & ". thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub date_add()
Dim i As Long
Dim dt As Worksheet

 Set dt = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Date")
 With dt
 lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
 For i = 1 To lastRow
     .Cells(i, 2).Formula = "=DATE(J1,J2,C" & i & ")"
 Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Where you input Year on J1, Month on J2 and the numbers of dates on column C

[image: Like this image]

Comment: indeed, i had almost your formula. <br>I just didn't add any spaces and used "&i&" which made the compilator bug. thanks a lot <br>PS: indeed, cells(i,2) is Bi

Answer (score 0):

Part of the answer.  Say cell **A1** contains the value *2*.  Running this:

```
Sub eddie()
    Dim i As Long, s As String
    i = Range("A1").Value
    s = "=DATE(20,20,20)"
    Cells(i, 2).Formula = s
End Sub
```

will place the formula in cell **B2**

[image]

Comment: That's as far as i was able to go. The trouble s that i need Date(j1,j2,cells(i-1)) where i is another parameter

Comment: i just forgot the spaces